# new WP_Query with order args – no more distinction between categories

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, order

I try to **change the post order** on all of my category/archive pages from the WP standard to having them sorted by their **modified date**. I modified a part of the `loop.php` from my theme (derived from *TwentyTen*) from this:

```
$post=$posts[0]; $c=0;  

while (have_posts()) : the_post();

$c++; if($c==1){$pcount='first';} else {$pcount='';}
```

To that:

```
$post=$posts[0]; $c=0;  

$args = array('orderby'=>'modified', 'order'=>'ASC');
$wkquery = new WP_Query( $args );
while ($wkquery->have_posts()) : $wkquery->the_post();

$c++; if($c==1){$pcount='first';} else {$pcount='';}
```

The problem now is: If I visit a category's archive, it lists the posts of **every** category I have. Before I added these lines it was just working as fine as in the default TwentyTen theme. What am I missing?

Comment: look at the `pre_get_post` filter, using `WP_Query` does not modify/extend the main loop, or replace it, it adds a new additional post loop and a tonne of new problems, e.g. you probably haven't noticed pagination doesn't work properly, or that if your new loop has 5 pages and the old loop has 4, page 5 will show a 404, or that performance is reduced. `pre_get_posts` can let you intercept the main query and modify its args ( aka `order` and `orderby` ). Your new loop doesn't limit itself to the current category because the only thing you told it is the order you want.

Answer (score 0):

On the template driving your archive page, you can use [the `query_posts()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) to adjust the main query (WordPress' default main query, not your custom one).

```php
query_posts( array(
    'orderby' => 'modified',
    'order' => 'ASC',
) );
```

Using [the `pre_get_posts` action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) is the better method, though slightly more complex (untested, would go in theme's `functions.php` or an mu-plugin):

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', static function ( $query ) {
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || ! $query->is_category() ) {
         return;
    }

    $query->set( 'orderby', 'modified' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
} );
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply and your suggestions! I will have to try the query_posts thing. I already tested this pre_get_posts thing in functions.php when I red about it on a wp-forum thread but unfortunately it didn’t do anything to the way my loop executes

Comment: Hmm. The only reason I can think of that `pre_get_posts` wouldn't work is that the custom query was in place, but was checking for the main query. Did you try `pre_get_posts` with the main query loop (not custom query loop)?

Comment: What does it mean, that a custom query is in place? How can I check if this is the case? Are we talking about the loop.php in my theme? I can spot this: 'while (have_posts()) : the_post();' At the end of the file I have  wp_reset_postdata();… Does that interrupt anything?

Comment: The phrase "custom query" means that a new `WP_Query` instance was created, rather than WordPress' main query.